# Why do I have GRUB and GRUB2 in my boot directory?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-loader, grub-legacy

I'm running F17 and my boot directory has grub and grub2. Why do I need both of these? I thought only one grub was required to boot. Does each one have specific properties?

Answer (score 1):

On my F17 box, I still have `/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz` which is meant to be the grub splash screen. It's contained in the `fedora-logos` package. The directory contains nothing else. My guess is this will be fixed sooner or later.

Comment: I have the same 'splash.xpm.gz' in 'grub'; however within grub2 I have 'device.map fonts grub.cfg grubenv i386-pc locale themes'